# A question of extension of vector bundles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Fix $p \in \mathbb{P}^1$. Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$, $C_1=\mathbb{P}^1\times \{p\}$ and $C_2=\{p\}\times \mathbb{P}^1$. Since $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{C_2},\mathcal{O}_{C_1})\cong \mathbb{C}$, there exists a nontrivial extension $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C_1} \rightarrow E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C_2} \rightarrow 0$. My question is, how should one understand this sheaf $E$? Is there an intuitive, geometric description of this sheaf $E$?

**Edit**
It turned out that I misunderstood something, and so I changed the latter half of the original question. Thank you for pointing out my confusion.

Comment: One point is that there is a bijection between the elements of $\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{C_1}, \mathcal{O}_{C_2})$ and extensions $0\to \mathcal{O}_{C_2} \to E \to \mathcal{O}_{C_1} \to 0$ *not* the extensions $0\to \mathcal{O}_{C_1} \to E \to \mathcal{O}_{C_2} \to 0.$

Comment: How did you come up with the isomorphism $\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{C_1}, \mathcal{O}_{C_2}) \cong \mathbb{C}?$

Comment: First, I think you need to adjust your notation: I am guessing you're talking about an extension of line bundles, in which case you should write $O(C_i)$, rather than $O_{C_i}$ (which means something completely different. Second, like Ehsan M. Kermani, I don't see how you get that Ext^1 is 1-dimensional: I calculate that $Ext^1=H^1(O(-1,1))$, which by the Kuenneth theorem is 4-dimensional.

Comment: I misunderstood something. I really mean by $\mathcal{O}_{C_i}$ the structure sheaf of subvarieties $C_i$. Not the line bundle $\mathbb{O}(C_i)$.